# Поиск числа в строке, исключая символ ! (восклицательный знак) слева и справа от числа

Tags: регулярные-выражения, oracle

Есть строка в поле БД:

```
INDEX-SOMETEXT SOME-DATA-TEXT 3454545759!722!NEXT-TEXT
```

Мне необходимо взять число 722 из этой строки, т.е. то число, которе находится между знаками !
Между знаками ! число может быть любой длины.

Пробовал так:

```
SELECT 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('INDEX-SOMETEXT SOME-DATA-TEXT 3454545759!722!NEXT-TEXT', '![^!][0-9]+!') 
FROM dual;
SELECT 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('INDEX-SOMETEXT SOME-DATA-TEXT 3454545759!722!NEXT-TEXT', '![0-9]+!') 
FROM dual;
```

Игры с [^!] [^!] [?(!)] [?<[!]] [?<(!)] результатов не дали, на выходе получаю строку **!722!**

Помогите составить выражение, что бы исключить ! из поиска и получить 722.

Oracle v 19.16.0.0.0 (из v$instance)

Comment: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '!', 2), '!', -1)`

Comment: @Akina Судя по ошибке и беглому поиску, функции **SUBSTRING_INDEX** нет в oracle, нашел в MySQL. Получаю ошибку ORA-00904: Invalid identifier (oracle 19)

Comment: Гм... а с чего я решил, что это мускуль? Обгляделся. Ну попробуй что-то типа `REGRXP_REPLACE(column, '^([^!]*!)([0-9]+)(!.*)$', '\2')`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

надо указать номер подвыражения

```
SELECT 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('INDEX-SOMETEXT SOME-DATA-TEXT 3454545759!722!NEXT-TEXT', '!(\d+)!', 1, 1, '', 1) 
FROM dual;
```